# how to define alternate soap web service using WSDL in php

Tags: php, soap, server, wsdl, client

I have a soap server and a soap client on different servers. My problem is that my internet link for soap server is flapping very frequently therefore I am deciding to take another internet link for soap server so if primary link down I will move to back up link and vice versa. But how I can tackle this condition in my php soap client that when IP change so address of wsdl change automatically instead of changing manually each time.
for example I have below WSDL links for two differnet IPS

```
<?php
$url1 = "http://x.x.x.x/api?wsdl"; //primary link IP
$url2 = "http://a.a.a.a/api?wsdl"; //back up link IP

$client = new SoapClient($url1 or $url2,array("trace"=>1,"exceptions"=>0));   //Now defining a client with url which is currently active.

?>
```

How to define th client after checking the active internet link at soap server?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution, you could just check if the primary wsdl can be accessed, and if it can't, use the secondary wsdl:

```
$url1 = "http://x.x.x.x/api?wsdl";
$url2 = "http://a.a.a.a/api?wsdl";

try {
  $headers = @get_headers($url1);
  if(!empty($headers)) {
    $wsdl = $url1;
  } else {
    $wsdl = $url2;
  }
  $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("trace"=>1,"exceptions"=>0));
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
```